# How to transfer seconds to Time format (YYYY:MM:DD HH:mm:ss) using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

### At first.

> I using moment.js to get the diff time between two 'moment.js objects'.
>
> `from` is the beginning time ; `to` is beginning time add the milliseconds.

### Variables

```
var from = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var to   = moment().milliseconds(ms).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

### Then I diff them.

```
var difftime = moment(to).diff(from);
```

If `from` is '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and 'to' is '2015-01-02 00:00:00', I will get the `difftime` is '86400000' (Seems like milliseconds format).

### My problem.

> How can I make `difftime(86400000)` transfer to `YYYY:MM:DD HH:mm:ss(0000:00:01 00:00:00)` ***using 'moment.js'***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) gives you a duration as milliseconds if you don't specify the unit. And unfortunately, there is no way for format a duration with momentjs.

Your best bet is to use this plugin: https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format/

Or you can do it manually. Create a [`moment.duration()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) object and create the string manually.

```
var from = moment();
var to   = moment().milliseconds(ms);
var dif = moment.duration(to.diff(from));
var string = dif.years() + "-" + dif.months() + "-" + dif.days() ...
```

But then you have to worry about padding zeros and it becomes a pain. So just use the plugin.